# Azure Authentification and Authorization

Tags: security, azure, azure-active-directory

I have a web application that I need to secure.

We phased the development tasks/epics to help the focus and meet the deadlines:

**Phase 1:**

- User authentication/authorization from active directory​
- Custom login page
- Custom user names (let users choose something like "John Doe" as a user name, I mean, spaces, no email address format)

**Phase 2:**

- External active directory integration (Fed​eration Services)

**Phase 3:**

- ​Open ID integration for users (Microsoft account, Facebook account, ...) ​

Additional info:

We have created a Windows Azure Active Directory but that seem to be problematic with both the user name and the login page. WAAD was chosen as it removes the pain of having to create a "custom" user management platform and because of the "as a service" approach.

I can't find anybody doing this on the web.

Would anybody have an idea to know how to start based on the requirements?

Comment: Based on the comments, I came to the point where I thing I need to use ASP.Net Identity. Users will NOT be in Active Directory but I can live with that as the 2 other points from phase one will be respected and phase 3 comes for (almost) free. However I need to validate that on top those authentication I can painlessly add support Organisational accounts (multiple Office365 and multiple on premise). Looks like I have the challenge of the day. I'll probably create a separate post for it.

Comment: And so I did: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23648836/asp-net-identity-and-multiple-login-mechanisms

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend starting by reading up on the [Claims-based Identity](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee517291.aspx) model. The current version of [WIF](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee748484.aspx) (Windows Identity Framework) supports claims based identity.

In a nutshell this model is much more extensible (say Federation) and you don't have to worry about the nitty gritty details of security code. You can start using claims now against your existing AD and then easily move to phase 2 and 3 by just pointing to, or adding, a new identity provider that you 'trust'.

Comment: I just did and indeed this seem promissing. Would you recommend the use of something like Thinktekture IdentityServer? It looks promissing

Comment: I was thinking that the Thinktekture server was only for development. Generally speaking a key concept with claims-based identity is you don't worry about authentication, you trust someone else to take care of that. i.e. think WAAD or ADFS. I found this PluralSight course ['Identity and Access Control in ASP.NET 4.5'](http://pluralsight.com/training/courses/TableOfContents?courseName=iac-aspnet&highlight=dominick-baier_iac-aspnet-m7-wsfed1*9#iac-aspnet-m7-wsfed1) outstanding.

Comment: Actually, what I need is some kind of mixed model (somehow like stackexchange) where users can either create an account on the website or connect using their provider. That being said, the ability to hook the active directory of a client is very important. I thought of using IdentityServer as my own private user store. I'll look into the 'is only for dev' thing, might be important to know that upfront...

Answer (score 0):

Azure AD will enable your customers to be able to sign in to your application using their on-premises (federated) AD identities or pure cloud managed identities (many O365 customers are pure cloud managed). Consumer IdP federation (MSA, Facebook, Google) isn't available with Azure AD yet - but it is something that is on our radar. Azure AD customers can already customize the sign-in page to add branding of their Organization - however the customization of sign-in page per application isn't available yet (also on our radar).

I am curious about the requirement of having arbitrary strings as username - why is this so important?

thanks

Comment: So basically your telling me Azure AD is NOT what I should use. I indeed came to the same conclusion in my research. Those items 'in your radar' will then come far too late for me. About the arbitrary strings as username, I thing having a username like name@theapp.com is extremely confusing for users. They will think it is an email address. Also, we have users who want to user 'firstname lastname' and I believe it makes sense. I know you could have 2 john doe but first come, first serve :D