# Asp.Net Identity and multiple login mechanisms

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-identity, asp.net-identity-2

I'd like to create an application that would be as open as possible to different login mechanisms.

So I've used Asp.Net Identity.

For (almost) free, this system gives me:

> - Simple accounts
> - OpenID with Facebook, Microsoft, Google and more

If you use the other templates, you can also have Organisational Accounts with the following 3 options:

> - Cloud - Single Organisation
> - Cloud - Multiple Organisations
> - On-Premises

My use cases are showing that I need a mix of all of that:

> - Users that want a simple account
> - Users that want to connect with OpenID
> - Companies that are using Office 365 and would like to SSO with our application
> - Companies that are using On-Premise Active Directory and would like to SSO with our application

While I could find a lot of documentation for each of those point separately, I fail to find one that would describe how to use them all in the same app.

So, is it at all possible? And of course, if yes, how are we supposed to get it to work?

Thanks,